# Photoshop: Why do file format options in the Save As menu differ from one file to another?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, file-format, save

These days it often happens that I have a PSD I'm working on and I want to save it out to some other format, BUT... Photoshop will not allow me to save it in the desired file format.

Example: I want to save as a **PNG** file, but can't. The option just isn't there. Others are missing too.

<sup>(Luckily the trusty [Pixar format](http://forums.cgsociety.org/t/pxr-whats-up-with-the-pixar-format/709889/2) is readily available, begging to be utilized should anyone need it.)</sup>

[image]

I've tried flattening the image, ensuring the color space is sRGB, reducing the bit depth to 8-bit when higher... but none of those things have solved the problem.

So what I have been doing is: Flatten Image, Select All, Copy, File > New, Paste, Flatten, Save As...

And magically, after that, all file formats become available. Yay! (But what a waste of time.)

[image]

So what's the big deal? Why doesn't Photoshop just allow me to save as a PNG or whatever I want to *directly from my original PSD*? Is this a bug? I don't remember this being an issue in older versions of Photoshop. If anyone knows why this is the case, or how to get around it, please share.

(And no, I don't want to do Export As instead, because it defaults to a save location other than that of the original PSD.)

Comment: PS removes possible formats from the `Save As` list if there are unsupported features in the file and while you're saying that your file was flat and 8b apparently there was something unsupported (maybe an additional channel?) — without the file it's impossible to say. Anyway, normally for stuff like PNG you're better of with `Export As` (or `Save as a Copy`)

Comment: @SergeyKritskiy Thank you! I will take your advice and `Save as a Copy`. I see that it defaults to the location of the original file. I get what you're saying about it not allowing us to save in formats that would not support all features, but TIFF for example does not even support *layers* (a very important feature!) and yet it is in the list. Whatever, I will stop trying to figure out Adobe's logic. :-)

Comment: Adobe supports layered tif. Other apps don't.